A bit of retro debugging that puzzle me! syser debugger: does really work on windows 7?
After just one BSOD I managed to get it working on windows xp sp2 in vmware 7.1.4 (Last version before syser 1.99.1900.1220 was out).
Now, according to the update log, version Windows 7 sp1 was supported since 1.99.1900.1207 Release.
All the following kernels' windows versions are patched in miCopyOnWrite, probably in order to preserve the breakpoint during the CoW (copy on write) process:
XP_SP2_ntkrnlpa,
XP_SP2_ntoskrnl,
XP_SP1_ntoskrnl,
XP_ntoskrnl,
W2K_ntkrnlpa,
W2K_ntoskrnl,
Vista_ntkrnlpa,
Vista_ntoskrnl,
VistaSP1_ntkrnlpa_6000_16584,
VistaSP1_ntoskrnl_6000_16584,
VistaSP1_ntkrnlpa_6001_18000,
VistaSP1_ntoskrnl_6001_18000,
W2003_ntkrnlpa,
W2003_ntoskrnl,
W2003_SP1_ntkrnlpa,
W2003_SP1_ntoskrnl,

And there is no Windows 7 patching, in 1.99.1900.1220
So, my question is, does anyone have experience using it in windows 7?
Did it work? It shouldn't if the kernel in windows 7 is not patched right?
